# Gradle exec task running shell script distracts asking for input

Tags: shell, unix, input, gradle

So I'm trying to get input from the user, specifically their password before we run some commands through sudo.  While using gradle to execute the shell script it prints out to the console something like

```
$ > Building > :gradletaskname
```

But when it asks for a password or other input it is not intuitive because the way gradle writes to the console it looks like the following.

```
$ > Building > :gradletasknamePassword:
```

I have tried echoing new lines but it always displays like my example above.  I know this might be a silly question but I've been beating my head on this for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known limitation and will be fixed in one of the next releases. Here's a link to the JIRA issue: http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1147